# Process only numeric values from input

Tags: jquery, facebook

I'm working with Facebook's API for a project, and basically I'm wanting to allow the user to input the URL from the post and the form grabs the ID from the URL before processing?

This is probably possible with Graph API, I've just not found anything as of yet, so apologies if this is located there.

URL Example: https://www.facebook.com/VivaLaCera/photos/a.765537340156803.1073741825.765537026823501/765537350156802/?type=1&theater

I'd like it to simply grab the post ID, which in this example, would be: 765537350156802

I'm probably over-complicating this too.

I've already attempted jQuery to process on button click;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {
        var val = document.getElementById('inputareaID').value;
        $('#inputareaID').val(val.substring(val.indexOf("/") + 1, val.indexOf('/?')));
    });
});
```

I'm still new to jQuery, so I'm aware the above isn't immaculate either.

Comment: is it not solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

What i have understand is you want the Post id from the url here is the code

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {
    var str = document.getElementById('inputareaID').value;
    var urlArray = str.split("/");
    var postID = urlArray[urlArray.length-2];
    alert(postID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the URL is *always* in that format you can simple just create an array by splitting at `/` and get the right value

```
var id = val.split('/')[6];
```

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {
     $('#inputareaID').val(function(_, t){
         return t.split('/')[6];
     });
});
```

Comment: Which part would this split? Since there's multiple "/"s in the URL.

Comment: All of them, it then creates an array and chooses the 6th key value